# UNION with Where - Getting fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have two tables in a DB (`table_1` and `table_2`), Each of them has a mutual column called `Name`.

I am currently using the following code to import some data (`Name`,`status`) only from `table_1`:

```
/* database section start */
    $mysqli = new mysqli("z","z","z","z");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
/* database section end */

// Choose Relevant items, and turn them into an array
$item_array = array(
'item1', 
'item2',
'item3'
);

//implode items, turn into string
$item_implode = join("','", $item_array);

//declare an overall array for result
$product = array();

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name, Status as status from table_1 where Name IN ('$item_implode') ORDER BY FIELD (Name, '$item_implode');");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $product_name = $row['Name'];
    // find all keys in $item_array which value is the products
        $keys = array_keys($item_array, $product_name);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {

        // add values for these keys
        $product[$key + 1]["Name"] = $row['Name'];
        $product[$key + 1]["status"] = $row['status'];//

    }
}
```

I want to import data from `table_2` as well (e.g., columns named `color`, `date_added`)

My objective is to have these keys:

```
$product[$x]["Name"]
$product[$x]["status"]
$product[$x]["color"]
$product[$x]["date_added"]
```

I've tried using UNION in this form, but getting fatal error on the last line:

```
$result = $mysqli->query

("(SELECT Name, status as status from table_1 where Name IN ('$item_implode') ORDER BY FIELD (Name, '$item_implode') ) 
UNION (SELECT color from table_2  where Name IN ('$item_implode') ORDER BY FIELD (Name, '$item_implode') );");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

EDIT:

Table_1:

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Name  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+           
| Name  | varchar(100)| NO   |     | None    |                |
| status| varchar(5)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table_2:

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Name  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+           
| Name  | varchar(100)| YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| color | varchar(5)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Update:**

Tried using this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query

("SELECT Name, status as status, color as color table_1 
JOIN table_2 ON table_1.Name=table_2.Name 
WHERE table_1.Name IN ('$item_implode') 
ORDER BY FIELD (table_1.Name, '$item_implode') ;" );

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

and got

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: it is not an union, it is a join on the mutual column

Comment: @LelioFaieta I was told I should use union... how should I make such a join, in a way that will not modify my original code too much?

Comment: What is your data. Create a sqlfiddle with data, show expected results in tabular form. Help us to help you. Otherwise we move on to the next question. And these just age off as they get pushed down.

Comment: @Drew Data is simple. Two tables. One mutual column named `Name` for both. The other columns of each table are not mutual.

Comment: If you lined it up like ducks for us, we could then test our theories against it. If our code hits your expected results, we know we are golden. Anyway, just food for thought for the future. It is not like this isn't an issue all day long trying to help people. Gotta move on to other stuff for me.

Comment: @Drew I've added tables to question.

Answer (score 0):

first of all what are those mysqli connection parameters??? 
Should they be like->`$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

Second of all UNION combines the result of two or more SELECT statements, what most probably you need is a Join Query! 
Which is something like

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the FROM word in first query?

```
("(SELECT Name, status as status table_1 where Name IN ('$item_implode') ORDER BY FIELD (Name, '$item_implode') ) UNION (SELECT color from table_2  where Name IN ('$item_implode') ORDER BY FIELD (Name, '$item_implode') );");
```

Comment: yes, that's just a typo in the question itself though

Comment: from Wiki:

In SQL the UNION clause combines the results of two SQL queries into a single table of all matching rows. The two queries must result in the same number of columns and compatible data types in order to unite. Any duplicate records are automatically removed unless UNION ALL is used.

Comment: So if you will use UNION you will fail since status and color will not merge as one column (and you do not need it). So use JOIN as suggested by others

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT Name, status as status, color 
    FROM table_1 
    JOIN table_2 ON table_1.Name=table_2.Name 
    WHERE table_1.Name IN ('$item_implode') 
    ORDER BY FIELD (table_1.Name, '$item_implode')
");
```

This query should do for you. I say should since I cannot test it without seeing a table structure, data and expected results.
This query will return a row for each item in the first table that have a corresponding row in the second. The correspondence is based on having the same Name in both tables

Comment: I'm not sure if this code doesn't work, or if I have some problem with `(` `;` signs. I've updated my question, if you see this is not correct please edit your answer with the full code, thanks